# Objective C initializing NSMutableArray with values

Tags: objective-c

I'm learning Obj-C and this is just syntax/language question.

Consider this code:

```
NSMutableArray *attributes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [attributes addObject:@"H:S"];
    [attributes addObject:@"H:W"];
    [attributes addObject:@"H:AGR"];
    [attributes addObject:@"H:TPC"];
    [attributes addObject:@"H:P"];
    [attributes addObject:@"H:TI"];
    return attributes;
```

Is there any shorter syntax to initialize array with preset values?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this shorthand syntax

```
NSArray *attributes = @[@"H:S",@"H:W",@"H:AGR",@"H:TPC",@"H:P",@"H:TI"];
```

if you need `NSMutableArray` you can do this

```
 NSMutableArray *attributes = [@[@"H:S",@"H:W",@"H:AGR",@"H:TPC",@"H:P",@"H:TI"] mutableCopy];
```

This will copy whole NSMUtableArray and copy all items to that will be bit performance issue if there are a lot of items, third option is below.

```
NSMutableArray *attributes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"H:S", @"H:W", @"H:AGR", @"H:TPC", @"H:P", @"H:TI", nil];
```

Comment: IS there any perofrmance diff between using mutable copy and basic init ?

Comment: There will be a performance issue in second case as it will first create an array then it will copy those items to another mutableArray, you can use third option as well, which is provide all items in init method parameter

Answer (score 1):

You can do it all in the `init` using `initWithObjects`:

```
NSMutableArray *attributes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"H:S", @"H:W", @"H:AGR", @"H:TPC", @"H:P", @"H:TI", nil];
```

or you can do it with the shorthand:

```
NSMutableArray *attributes = @[@"H:S", @"H:W", @"H:AGR", @"H:TPC", @"H:P", @"H:TI"].mutableCopy
```

The disadvantage to the second one is that it first creates an `NSArray` and then copies it. So there is a (very) slight performance tradeoff for short code/readability.