# Multiply array elements of type double

Tags: ios, c, arrays

I have this array.

```
double numbers[] = {40.0, 8.0, 45.0, 55.0, 30.0, 10.0, 20.0};
```

and some multiplier

```
CGFloat multiplier = 2.67;
```

I want to multiply each element of numbers array by multiplier. 
So the array will be like

```
double numbers[] = {106.80, 21.36, 120.15, 146.85, 80.1, 26.7, 53.4};
```

I am getting "Sending 'double' to parameter of incompatible type 'id _Nonnull".

And what is easiest way to find max no in that numbers array.

Comment: Any reason you aren't using an actual NSArray?

Comment: I want to maintain array of double values

Comment: Well, you've used the NSArray tag, but that is not an NSArray. NSArray holds *objects* (eg pointers) but you have a straight-up array of Double values. My guess is that you're trying to do something with it that implies it is an NSArray, when it is not. What line of code is giving you the error you referenced?

Comment: @matt Probably the person is a newbie and therefore doesn't completely know the differences between these. While it's extra you did point him the issues, removed them as he will be able to improve himself, I don't understand the second point about "whining" - it was quite aggressive and unnecessary. Everyone makes mistakes and in Q&A sites we're improving ourselves both in terms of asking questions and technical knowledge, so just let people learn and please be a bit more peaceful :-) Have a nice evening!

Comment: @matt there is nothing new in your first comment, you just edited the comment by stonz2

Answer (score 1):

C arrays are faster than ObjC `NSArray`s but the current devices are quite fast and thus it's often better to write the code using objects, losing the speed but improving readability.

The solution to your question "I want to multiply each element of numbers array by multiplier. And what is easiest way to find max no in that numbers array." is:

```
double numbers[] = {40.0, 8.0, 45.0, 55.0, 30.0, 10.0, 20.0};
CGFloat multiplier = 2.67;
double maxValue = -DBL_MAX;
for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(double)); i++) {
    numbers[i] *= multiplier; // multiply value
    maxValue = MAX(numbers[i], maxValue); // find max value
}
NSLog(@"Max=%f.2", maxValue);
```

The output is following:

```
(double) maxValue = 146.84999999999999
(double [7]) numbers = ([0] = 106.8, [1] = 21.359999999999999, [2] = 120.14999999999999, [3] = 146.84999999999999, [4] = 80.099999999999994, [5] = 26.699999999999999, [6] = 53.399999999999999)
```

But if you're doing it by mistake, lack of knowledge or whatever: I would strongly advise using `NSArray`s unless the performance is the known issue here.

Comment: Plus, with an NSArray, you can use `[array valueForKeyPath:@"@max.self"]` to quickly find the maximum in the array.

Comment: With finding the "max" amongst FP numbers with NaN, code could  use `double max = NAN; ... if (!(numbers[i] <= max)) max = numbers[i];` as an alternative to `double max = -DBL_MAX; ` to detect the max against even a list of one `-DBL_MAX` or `-INF`.

Comment: @chux Interesting idea, thanks! The only thing is that the person handling such method needs to remember to handle NAN value, anyway it's very interesting approach!

Answer (score 1):

As you need a loop anyway to multiply each element you can add a line to check and set the maximum value

```
CGFloat multiplier = 2.67;
double numbers[] = {40.0, 8.0, 45.0, 55.0, 30.0, 10.0, 20.0};
int numberOfElements = sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(double);
double max = 0.0;

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) {
    numbers[i] *= multiplier;
    if (numbers[i] > max) max = numbers[i];
}
NSLog(@"maximum value: %f", max);
```

Comment: The problem with this answer is that you're assuming the numbers are positive. If the array changes, you will neglect all negative values (if the whole array will be negative, the output will be invalid). Due to that, `max` should be declared as `-DBL_MAX` instead of `0`.

Comment: I understand your point but in the question the numbers **are** positive.

Comment: @vadian don't rely on anecdotal evidence sets, and NEVER underestimate the potential stupidity of users. ;)

Comment: Well in such case in fact you can even compare to 8 (or 16 in fact), because in this example all numbers are higher than this :) If the person who asks the question will make a function out of this, he may fail. Also, while your answer is correct, it's Q&A site, so maybe it's worth to show that there are also other elements to pay attention to. No stress, have a nice day :-)

Comment: Minor: `sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0])` is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

I would write the code in Objective-C instead of C:

```
NSMutableArray* numbers = 
    [@[@40.0, @8.0, @45.0, @55.0, @30.0, @10.0, @20.0] mutableCopy];
CGFloat multiplier = 2.67;
[numbers enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber* obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL* stop) {
    numbers[idx] = @(obj.doubleValue * multiplier);
}];
```

Bonus result of that approach: you can then get the maximum simply by saying `[numbers valueForKeyPath:@"@max.self"]`.

But even more than Objective-C, I would write the code in Swift. You are evidently a beginner, and Objective-C and C are not beginner languages. This is so easy and simple in Swift!

```
var arr = [40.0, 8.0, 45.0, 55.0, 30.0, 10.0, 20.0]
let multiplier = 2.67
arr = arr.map {$0 * multiplier}
let max = arr.max()
```

Comment: 3 minor points: 1) On the first line you can create an object immediately as mutable version - here you're first creating it as immutable, then doing a (mutable) copy of the object(array in this case). 2) In modern ObjC you can use `@(newValue)` instead of `[[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:newValue]`. 3) Also you can immediately in enumeration declare types instead of casting it later: `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber *number, NSUInteger idx[...]`.

Comment: @Vive "On the first line you can create an object immediately as mutable version" How?

Comment: I guess in this case the most memory-efficient would be: `[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@40.0, @8.0, @45.0, @55.0, @30.0, @10.0, @20.0, nil]`. But in case someone really wants to have memory-efficient code plain C arrays are much much faster than ObjC (still, ObjC should be preferred if no memory issues come into consideration).

Comment: @Vive that is no more "memory-efficient" than what I did. Not one little bit. Nor is it any more "immediately as mutable version" than what I did.

Comment: Your code firstly creates an immutable version, then copies it to mutable version. What is more, I wrote a simple loop test checking both possibilities and on 100'000 cycles the time is 0.262631 for your init and 0.232170 for mine. Also here (all) people also seem to have the same point of view as me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34952551/849616. Can you explain why do you think otherwise?

Comment: When you do a mutable copy of an array, the _elements_ of the array are not copied. It's a shallow copy of the array; it contains identically the same objects as the original. It's a perfectly standard way of transforming an NSArray into an NSMutableArray.

Comment: You can see that the times are different and with mutableCopy it is 13% slower (I've tested on iPhone 5, iOS 10.3 simulator - you can perform your test). Copying an array/dict creates a completely new array of pointers to the objects inside the original array - so it's a shallow copy of objects inside the array, but not the array itself.

Comment: 13% slower for such a tiny time is really not a source of worry. Premature optimization and all that. I don't see that as less "immediate" in the real world. And you need to make up your mind what you're objecting to; before, it was "memory-efficient". :)